# how to pass cloud log query as filter in the python code

Tags: python-3.x, google-cloud-logging

I have created a cloud log query as follows in which I get all logs of the airflow dag run. I want to get all the logs saved in the cloud sql using python.

```
    resource.type="composername"
    severity=(ERROR OR WARNING OR INFO)
    logName=("projects/projectname/logs/airflow-worker" OR "projects/projectname/logs/airflow- 
    scheduler")
    labels.workflow:"DAG_NAME"
    labels.task-id:"task1"
    textPayload:"exception"

    FILTER = "timestamp>=2022-05-16T14:26:50.943463+00:00 AND timestamp<2022-05- 
    16T14:27:21.368493+00:00 AND labels.workflow:ibis_secret"
    entries = client.list_entries(filter_=FILTER,order_by=None) 
    for entry in logger.list_entries():
    #print(type(entry))
    # print("##",entry)
    timestamp = entry.timestamp.isoformat()
    print('* {} -> {}'.format (timestamp,  entry.payload))
    data = entry.payload
```

Error is like:-

```
   raise exceptions.from_grpc_error(exc) from exc
   google.api_core.exceptions.InvalidArgument: 400 Unparseable filter: 
   syntax error at line 1, column 26, token ':';
   syntax error at line 1, column 64, token ':';
   syntax error at line 1, column 65, token '00'
```

When i am trying to pass the timestamp with timing and timezone its giving error and when I remove the timestamp its working fine. Also I needed information on how to pass the cloud query log in the filter so I can get respective dagname dag logging in the above python code . Please let me know if anyone has an idea or suggestion for this.

Answer (score 0):

Enclose your timestamps in double quotes. Your `FILTER` should be:

```
FILTER = 'timestamp >= "2022-05-16T14:26:50.943463+00:00" AND timestamp < "2022-05-16T14:27:21.368493+00:00" AND labels.workflow:ibis_secret'
```